# How to reduce the width of the equation in a text paragraph?

Tags: equations

How to reduce the width of the equation in a text paragraph?

For example:

```
Paragraphs and new lines it might be desirable to wrap text around a
$(N-1)$-order float (a figure, in our case) so as ... The package may
not come with the $(N-1)$-order default installation of LaTeX. It may
be noted that the width of $(N-1)$-order the image included was
specified relative to.
```

[image]

The equation (N-1) is too loose, how to deal with it?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to be, but you could use `$(N{-}1)$`. Not sure whether you'd be able to sleep at night though.

Comment: @Werner Honestly, the other night I woke up in a cold sweat after dreaming I left a blank line before an `equation` environment in the middle of a paragraph ... :P :P

Answer (score 9):

I can reproduce the picture with

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}

\textwidth=.76\textwidth

\begin{document}

Paragraphs and new lines it might be desirable to wrap text
around a $(N-1)$-order float (a figure, in our case) so as ...
The package may not come with the $(N-1)$-order default
installation of LaTeX. It may be noted that the width of
$(N-1)$-order the image included was specified relative to.

\end{document}
```

[image]

This shows an obvious mistake: math is in Computer Modern, while the text is in Times. These fonts are visually incompatible. If I change `\usepackage{times}` into `\usepackage{mathptmx}`, I get

[image]

The result is not as “loose” as in the previous case and the fonts are compatible.

Better yet, use NewTX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\textwidth=.76\textwidth

\begin{document}

Paragraphs and new lines it might be desirable to wrap text
around a $(N-1)$-order float (a figure, in our case) so as ...
The package may not come with the $(N-1)$-order default
installation of LaTeX. It may be noted that the width of
$(N-1)$-order the image included was specified relative to.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you may want to avoid the spaces around the minus signs to participate in stretching or shrinking of interword spaces for justification, which can be accomplished by adding braces; this also avoids the risk that there is a line break after the minus sign, like in your picture.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\textwidth=.76\textwidth

\begin{document}

Paragraphs and new lines it might be desirable to wrap text
around a ${(N-1)}$-order float (a figure, in our case) so as ...
The package may not come with the ${(N-1)}$-order default
installation of LaTeX. It may be noted that the width of
${(N-1)}$-order the image included was specified relative to.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Final attempt (not really recommended): also reduce the space around the minus sign, but not remove it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\Nminusone}{$\medmuskip=1mu{(N-1)}$}

\textwidth=.76\textwidth

\begin{document}

Paragraphs and new lines it might be desirable to wrap text
around a \Nminusone-order float (a figure, in our case) so as ...
The package may not come with the \Nminusone-order default
installation of LaTeX. It may be noted that the width of
\Nminusone-order the image included was specified relative to.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The question is phrased about changing the width of N-1 but the implied reason was to affect one particular linebreak in a paragraph. Note that TeX does a least cost optimisation of breaks over a whole paragraph, so changing a single math expression may change all the line breaking in the paragraph before and after that point so it is very hard to say in general whether making it wider or narrower would affect the break at that spot.

It is better, if possible, to approach line breaking problems via settings on the whole paragraph. here I set your same text, with various settings (but some have far worse problems than your original broken N-1 :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,ragged2e}

\textwidth=.76\textwidth
\advance\textheight10\baselineskip

\begin{document}

\newcommand\p{%
Paragraphs and new lines it might be desirable to wrap text
around a $(N-1)$-order float (a figure, in our case) so as ...
The package may not come with the $(N-1)$-order default
installation of LaTeX. It may be noted that the width of
$(N-1)$-order the image included was specified relative to.\par}

\newcommand\sep{\smallskip\hrule\smallskip}

%default
\p 

\sep

% try to make one more line
{\looseness=1 \p}

\sep

% try (fail) to make one less  line
{\looseness=-1 \p}

\sep

% make one more line without just pushing one word on to the last line
% makes text horribly loose in this case
{\looseness=1 \parfillskip=.5\textwidth\emergencystretch=2cm \p}

\sep 

% aggressively tight spacing
{\spaceskip=.1em plus .1em 
\medmuskip=2mu minus 2mu
\p}

\sep 

% default ragged right
{\raggedright\p}

\sep 

% RaggedRight setting which allows less variability in the
% right margin, which causes a generally more even effect
% although not very obvious here.
{\RaggedRight\p}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to shrink the width of the equation using the `graphics` package and the `\scalebox` command. The `{.9}` makes it take up 90% of the usual horizontal space, and `[1]` keeps the vertical height the same.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}

Paragraphs and new lines it might be desirable to wrap text around a
\scalebox{.9}[1]{$(N-1)$}-order float (a figure, in our case) so as ... The package may
not come with the \scalebox{.9}[1]{$(N-1)$}-order default installation of LaTeX. It may
be noted that the width of \scalebox{.9}[1]{$(N-1)$}-order the image included was
specified relative to.

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Instead of the original paragraph:

[image]

Comment: no please never do that in a real document.